# Graph search with constraints on edge type

Tags: search, graph, constraints

I'm looking for the right keywords/nomenclature for the following problem, since I cannot find anything on google to this topic:

I have a graph where each edge and each node is assigned to a certain class/color or whatever you call it. Now I want to find a path between a start and a goal node, having some constraints on the path. For example I'd like to have as less "blue" nodes on the path as possible, or max. 2 "red" edges, or a combination of those things. Of course there are also the usual edge costs, which have to be minimized in addition to the fixed path constraints.

How is this kind of problem called, or what do I have to search for?

Best regards
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that a name for such a general problem exists. However, I'm pretty certain you can re-model your graph and solve this problem via a simple Dijkstra search:

- Trying to avoid certain (type of) vertex: Say you have a vertex that is to be avoided, and that has k neighbors. Replace it by a K_k (i.e. a clique with k vertices), and connect each neighbor to one of the k new vertices. Then set the weight of all the clique-edges to something large. Now every path passing over the original vertex will have to pass through the clique and "pay the fee", i.e. it will be avoided, if possible
- Trying to avoid certain edges: Just raise their edge weight accordingly

Then, run a simple Dijkstra search. If you have multiple classes that are to be avoided, you can even set the weights as to determine priorities for avoiding each of them..

Hope that helps,
Lukas

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I had some similar thoughts too, but simpy raising the edge weights cannot cover all the constraint variants. Suppose we want to visit an edge max 3 times. Then any path containing 3 or less is perfectly fine, so raising the weights here might result in a different (worse) path choice. An approach would be to dynamically change the weights once the constraint isn't satisfied anymore, but I'm not sure if it always results in an optimal path.

Comment: Oh, now you even have "up to x times the same edge"-constraints? You didn't mention these in your original post. 

You definitely have to fully specify your problem before anyone will be able to help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: sorry I thought I actually did in here: " For example I'd like to have as less "blue" nodes on the path as possible, _or max. 2 "red" edges_, or a combination of those things. "

Comment: And actually we don't have a full specification of the constraints right now since the hole project is at it's beginning, I just hoped to get the names of some algorithms solving similar problems